# How to remove pattern stuffs from preg_replace results?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code :

```
$text='This [word] should be a link';
echo preg_replace('/\[\w+\]/', "<a href='#'>$0</a>", $text);
```

Output :

```
This <a href='#'>[word]</a> should be a link
```

How can i have this output :

```
This <a href='#'>word</a> should be a link
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capturing group and use `$1` in replacement:

```
echo preg_replace('/\[(\w+)\]/', "<a href='#'>$1</a>", $text);
This <a href='#'>word</a> should be a link
```

Comment: What about this `preg_replace('/\[(\w+)\]/', '<a href="#">\1</a>', $text);` ?

Comment: I avoid that, because of encountering replacement text that contained `$0` it was some lame'o  JS I had to replace stuff in, and let em tell you it having `$0` in there was bad mojo, lol.  Took me ages to figure out the problem.